# Angular translate pipe in condition

Tags: angular, translate

I am trying to make condition in template for translate, like this

```
{{showBigMap ? 'Shared.ShowMap' | translate : 'Shared.HideMap' | translate }}
```

But it does not compile, it got errors, my question is how I can use translate in condition in angular component template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{{showBigMap ? ('Shared.ShowMap' | translate ): ('Shared.HideMap' | translate) }}
```

Wrap it in brackets

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to write it in more readable way:

```
{{ (showBigMap ? 'Shared.ShowMap' : 'Shared.HideMap') | translate }}
```